# How to remove or drop duplicates based on two column (ID and quarter)? R Studio

Tags: r, filter, duplicates, drop

My `dataframe2` looks like this

```
dataframe2 = structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), 
                            Quarterly = c(2006.1, 2006.1, 2006.1, 2006.2, 2006.3, 2006.4, 2006.1, 2006.2, 2006.3, 
                                          2006.3, 2006.4, 2006.1, 2006.1, 2006.1, 2006.2, 2006.2, 2006.3, 2006.4), 
                            Status = c("Employed", "Employed", "Employed", "Employed", "Null", "Employed", "Employed",
                                       "Employed", "Employed", "Employed", "Employed", "Null", "Null", "Employed", 
                                       "Employed", "Employed", "Employed", "Employed")), 
                       class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -18L))
```

```
ID   Quarterly    Status 
1    2006.1     Employed 
1    2006.1     Employed 
1    2006.1     Employed 
1    2006.2     Employed 
1    2006.3     Null 
1    2006.4     Employed 
2    2006.1     Employed 
2    2006.2     Employed 
2    2006.3     Employed 
2    2006.3     Employed 
2    2006.4     Employed 
3    2006.1     Null 
3    2006.1     Null 
3    2006.1     Employed 
3    2006.2     Employed 
3    2006.2     Employed 
3    2006.3     Employed 
3    2006.4     Employed
```

I'm keen for it to look like this, so that there is only one observation per `ID`

```
ID   Quarterly    Status 
1    2006.1.    Employed 
1    2006.2     Employed 
1    2006.3     Null 
1    2006.4     Employed 
2    2006.1     Employed 
2    2006.2     Employed 
2    2006.3     Employed 
2    2006.4     Employed 
3    2006.1     Null 
3    2006.2     Employed 
3    2006.3     Employed 
3    2006.4     Employed
```

I've tried a couple of options that I had found on this website, and none have worked as hoped. I did:
(a)
`group_by(ID,Quarterly) %>% filer(n()>1)`
and (b)
`group_by(ID,Quarterly) %>% distinct(ID, keep.all = TRUE)`.
Option (b) just removed all the `Quarterly` values except `2023.1` (the latest my dates go to).

Comment: Please try your reprex before posting, it is not reproducible.

Comment: If you were doing it with `duplicated` you could paste the two columns together and let that be the vector that is examined.

Comment: Simply `dataframe2[!duplicated(dataframe2[-3]), ]`?

Comment: Also if you do group_by(ID, quarter) you can use e.g. slice_head(n=1) ... but are you sure that they will always be duplicates in Status?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to do it with `dplyr` is using summarise

```
result <- dataframe2  |> summarise(.by = c("ID", "Quarterly"), first(Status))
```

For simplicity, I took the function first to summarize the group over ID and Quaterly

Answer (score 0):

You may use `dplyr::slice_head` for the purpose of selecting one row (first in this case) per `group` passed in as `by` argument.

```r
library(dplyr)

dataframe2 %>% 
  slice_head(n = 1, by = c(ID, Quarterly))
#>    ID Quarterly   Status
#> 1   1    2006.1 Employed
#> 2   1    2006.2 Employed
#> 3   1    2006.3     Null
#> 4   1    2006.4 Employed
#> 5   2    2006.1 Employed
#> 6   2    2006.2 Employed
#> 7   2    2006.3 Employed
#> 8   2    2006.4 Employed
#> 9   3    2006.1     Null
#> 10  3    2006.2 Employed
#> 11  3    2006.3 Employed
#> 12  3    2006.4 Employed
```

<sup>Created on 2024-03-05 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>